# It is possible for Google Search to give me results (prioritized) from Google History/Bookmarks?

Tags: google-search, google-bookmarks

The title pretty much summarizes what I want to know. Long time ago, I remember something called Google Custom Search, but I'm afraid that Google shut down that service too.
Anyway, I love to bookmark on Google Bookmarks and also I like that Google keeps a record of every single search that I make, but it seems that Google Search doesn't want to include them on my normal queries.

I want to know if I can configure to do that. No plugins, no URLs other than Google.com. Is this possible? If so, please tell me how.

Comment: Google Custom Search is alive and well and can be found at https://cse.google.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Google's Chrome browser, or Firefox (optionally with the awesome Omnibar add-on), you will get direct suggestions from your history/bookmarks, if you search from the browser's address bar.

The matching is based on keywords -and optionally bookmark tags-, but I am not sure if the results (= suggestions) are prioritized on their type.

Comment: That is the thing @pleinolihg I wonder if Google do that! My guess is that they doesn't do that because the may close bookmarks service someday.

Comment: Also, my problem with the plugins is that I used several Google Chrome/Firefox profiles. Don't ask :)

Comment: Well, I suppose Google themselves don't integrate your bookmarks when you do a search, although I can't back that up with facts. I have no idea browse history-wise.

Comment: @pleinolijf, it will search your Chrome bookmarks, not your Google Bookmarks

Comment: ok, for me is pretty clear now, it seems that google doesn't have a way integrate those results on search but I have to look in the google.com/bookmarks it self, thank to all

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I came here for the same answer. So for other people's reference:
Indeed, I have witnessed this functionality in the past too, namely that google search also shows results "of the content of the pages of your bookmarks" if you wished. I also have been searching for a long time to get this back.  But unless google doesn't turn it back, it won't.  Add-ons can not access the content of those bookmarked pages inside Google's database unfortunatly.
Let's cry together.