# Show search results from my Google Bookmarks while doing a Google search

Tags: google-search, google-bookmarks

When I do a Google search, is there way (or setting) to show results from links stored in my Google Bookmarks (if any) at the top and then after that results from web? As of now, I have to search in Google Bookmarks separately.

Comment: Seems like someone asked this last year. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33328/it-is-possible-for-google-search-to-give-me-results-prioritized-from-google-hi

Comment: @winterswift: I use Google Chrome but it has never shown me search results from my Google Bookmarks (the ones on https://www.google.com/bookmarks/ and **not** bookmarks of Google Chrome)

Comment: Yeah, figured. Not that it's a good long-term solution, but you can always export your Google Bookmarks and re-import them to Chrome. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Chrome, install the [BookMark Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-search/hhmokalkpaiacdofbcddkogifepbaijk) extension (by Alvin Wong) and just type `bm&lt;space&gt;` in the Omnibar and enter your query. Very useful.